# Read a file to a 2D array in C

Tags: c, parsing, file-io, multidimensional-array

I'm learning C and I decided to make a text game as my *learning project*. So I'm trying this primitive "parser" that reads a text file into a 2D array, but there's a problem: this map doesn't use 1 character-wide cells, it uses 2 character-wide cells. For instance, the player is represented with a `**`, a door is represented like `##` and so on.

That means, I need to read 2 characters of the text file and then assign it to the respective cell in the map.

Well, I made a test file that contains

```
aabbccddee
ffgghhiijj
kkllmmnnoo
ppqqrrsstt
uuvvwwxxyy
```

And I tried to read it with

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 5 
#define COLS 5

int main() {
    FILE *mapfile = fopen("durr", "r");
    char charbuffer[3], row, col, *map[ROWS][COLS];

    /* Initializing array */
    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            map[row][col] = "  ";
        }
    }

    /* Reading file into array */
    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            map[row][col] = fgets(charbuffer, 3, mapfile);
        }
    }

    /* Printing array */
    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            printf("%s", map[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(mapfile);    
    return 0;
}
```

But when I execute it, I get this

```
uuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuu
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that fgets return a pointer, but I'm not sure. I tried doing it with fgetc but it looks messy and I dropped it after reading about gets.

Comment: There are no *strings* in C, only character arrays. Hence *you cannot assign "strings"*! Instead, use `strncpy()`, and make sure you understand the memory management that's involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have strdup'ed the contents read from the file.  Replace the file reading block with this:

```
/* Reading file into array */
for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        if (fgets(charbuffer, 3, mapfile))
            map[row][col] = strdup(charbuffer);
    }
}
```

and don't forget to put this at the beginning of your code too:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. I was looking for a way of (somehow) dereferencing the return value of fgets but yes, this is what I was looking for. It kinda works now, it's all weirdly formatted. Like this http://pastebin.com/1F2D5zNp. Could it be I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: If the idea is to learn C, then he should be getting used to malloc, not invoking a function that isn't even part of the standard.

Comment: It was because of the array sizes, I would say.  Don't forget that `fgets` not only reads upto, but also puts, EOF to the buffer.

Comment: @MattPhillips I do agree with what you said.  But I also have to remind you that `POSIX` is a valid standard.

Comment: Oh, Matt and shinkou, you're right. Guess I'll have to figure out how to solve that problem. And I come from higher-level languages so I never managed memory manually, so I'll read a bit more about that. Thanks, guys.

Comment: Wait, you mean fgets is not part of the standard?

Comment: @user1002327 `fputs` conforms to C89 and C99, while `strdup` conforms to POSIX.1-2001.

Comment: @user1002327 I was referring to strdup.  shinkou, duly noted.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that

```
char *map[ROWS][COLS];
```

only allocates space for ROWS x COLS char *pointers*, it does not allocate space for the strings themselves.  So you're continually overwriting charbuffer as you've done it with every  iteration, which explains why you end up with the same characters repeated over and over when you read out.  You need to dynamically allocate the memory you need, along the lines of

```
for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        charbuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);  //****
        map[row][col] = fgets(charbuffer, 3, mapfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh, I'm getting `incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’`. Maybe I'm missing something? Could it be my gcc? Oh, and I had to change charbuffer[3] with *charbuffer, otherwise I'd get a `incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[3] from type ‘char *’` error.

Comment: @user1002327 Right about charbuffer[3] -> charbuffer*, forgot to mention that.  As for malloc, try #include "stdlib.h".