# Inputting & Displaying Two Dimensional Character Arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to read in a user input file(which is a 14 x 28 text file of all numbers), as a two dimensional character array. Which I think I have done with this code:

```
getline(cin, fileName);
cout << "\n";
infile.open(fileName.c_str());
if (infile.is_open())
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++)
        infile >> map[i][j];
cout << map[14][28];
```

However, with this code, I can't seem to send the array to output for viewing. When I try to view the contents of the array the program returns a strange symbol that looks like an e... This doesn't seem to be a memory address so I'm not sure what this  number is.

I also need to represent numbers within my map array as letters. Such as a 0 being a ' ', a 1 being a '*', 2 being a "W" and a  3 being a "k".

I'm unsure as to how I should code the array so the numbers will appear as letters when the contents are displayed.

So in summation,
      1. How do I properly input a two dimensional character array?
      2. How do I code this array so its numbers are represented by letters?
      3. And how do I display this array in output?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Try searching for "c++ read file 2d array".

Comment: `cout << map[14][28];` is likely wrong - also ensure the map is holding arithmetic values (no char, signed/unsigned char)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a file to a 2D array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816161/read-a-file-to-a-2d-array-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another loop, similar to the one you used to read in `map`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++) {
        cout << map[i][j] << ","; // You can use a comma or whatever you want, like a space, etc.
    }
    cout << endl; // So each row is broken up, else it will all be on a single long line
}
```

If you create a `Map` class, you could override the `<<` operator so doing `cout << myMap` would output like this example above, and if you decide to change how it looks, you only need to change it in a single location (within the `Map` class).

You updated your original post, I see.

One reason that you see unusual characters when you print it out, is that an array of `char` is displayed as its ASCII equivalent instead of it numerical value. You must cast it to an `(int)` if you want to see actual numbers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++) {
        cout << (int)map[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

When you output, you can check each value before printing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++) {
        if (map[i][j] == 0) cout << " ";
        else if (map[i][j] == 1) cout << "*";
        else if (map[i][j] == 2) cout << "W";
        else if (map[i][j] == 3) cout << "k";
        else cout << (int)map[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Changing that `if...else if` to a `switch` statement is another alternative, or even creating a "replacement array" which includes a structure like:

```
string replacement = " *Wk";
```

And then checking whether `map[i][j] < 4`. If that evaluated true, you would use

```
if (map[i][j] < 4) {
    cout << replacement[ map[i][j] ];
else
    cout << (int)map[i][j];
```

Comment: This is definitely helping, I can now output the array in the 14 x 28 fashion but there are still a few weird characters at the bottom. Assigning letters to the numbers also isn't quite working but this answer has given me much more to work with.

Comment: If you update your original question (append to it so people can see both the "before" and "after") with the "weird characters" that you see in your output, it might help others identify what causes those to print unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

If map is declared as

```
            char map[14][28];
```

then the statement

```
           cout<< map[14][28];
```

should crash. Since the last valid index of map would be [13][27] (array indexing is 0 based) and you are trying to access a memory which is out of bounds. To display all characters, you should use loops similar to the input.

Comment: I don't necessarily think that it *should* crash. It definitely *does* invoke undefined behavior, one option of which is that it *may* crash. There are quite a few other possibilities, though...