# reading file and storing in array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a maze input file, maze.txt, that looks like this:

```
    #.#######
    #.......#
    ####.####
    #....#..#
    #.####.##
```

Where "#" represents the walls, and "." represents the passable cells. I want to be able to read in this file using input redirection:

```
    mazeprogram.exe < maze.txt
```

I want to be able to print out how many rows and columns are in this maze, something like this:

```
    ##..##############
    ##..............##
    ########..########
    ##........##....##
    ##..########..####
```

I also want to stick with using scanf(), as I am trying to get better at the basics of c programming.

So far I am have trouble assigning the rows and columns to a 2d array. This is what I have so far:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define MAX_HEIGHT 100
    #define MAX_WIDTH 100
    #define wall "#"
    #define path_cell "."

    typedef struct {
        char type;
        int visited;
        int final_path;
    } mazecells_t;

    typedef struct {
        int height;
        int width;

        mazecells_t M[MAX_HEIGHT][MAX_WIDTH];

   } m_type;

   void read_maze(m_type *maze);

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       m_type MAZE;

       read_maze(&MAZE);

       return 0;
   }

   void 
   read_maze(m_type *maze) {
       int row=0, col=0;

       scanf("%d %d", &maze->height, &maze->width);

       for (row=0; row < maze->height; row++) {

           for(col=0; col < maze->width; col++) {
               maze -> M[row][col]; 
           }
       }
    }
```

I know that my code so far is not right, I'm just having difficulty assigning the rows and columns from the maze input to a 2d array. I would like to be able to do that so I can print the columns and rows. If I'm not going in the right direction, any help to get me on the right track would be appreciated.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a file to a 2D array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816161/read-a-file-to-a-2d-array-in-c)

Comment: `read_maze` isn't really doing anything except reading two integers.

Comment: @Chirstoph Terasa , Is there a better approach to this? Like what would I have to do in order to get closer to the result I want?

Comment: @Ani Menon, I don't think this is much of a duplicate to that question, I think I just didn't name my title properly.

Comment: @RoadRunner, if you're certain your maze is always rectangular, simply read the amount of characters on the first line to get the number of columns, and count the number of newlines to get the number of rows. You could also just read the amount of characters on the first line and divide by the size of the file in bytes to get the number of rows.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Christoph Terasa. Would it be okay if you can show me an example of how I can do this? I'm just not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
void
read_maze(m_type *maze) {
    int row=0, col=0;
    char ch;

    while(EOF != scanf("%c", &ch)){
        if(ch == wall || ch == path_cell){//#define wall '#' #define path_cell '.'
            maze->M[row][col].type = ch;
            maze->M[row][col].visited = 0;
            maze->M[row][col].final_path = 0;
            ++col;
        } else if(ch == '\n'){
            maze->width = col;//uncheck same size and max size limit
            col = 0;
            ++row;
        }
    }
    if(col != 0)
        ++row;//uncheck max size limit

    maze->height = row;

    printf("maze has %d rows and %d columns\n", maze->height, maze->width);
    for (row = 0; row < maze->height; row++) {
        for(col = 0; col < maze->width; col++) {
            putchar(maze->M[row][col].type); 
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @BLUEPIXY, this works great.

Comment: would there be a way to modify this for the modified output in my question at the bottom? I just edited it then, it makes the maze more readable.

Comment: @RoadRunner `putchar(maze->MAZE[row][col].type);` --> `putchar(maze->MAZE[row][col].type);putchar(maze->MAZE[row][col].type);` but It's bad idea because it view and model are different.

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY, I think your right about that. Really top answer man :)